# Not getting a desired output

Tags: python

```
class EPL_Team:

    def __init__(self, name, song = "No Slogan", title = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.song = song
        self.title = title

    def increaseTitle(self, title = 0):
        self.title = title
        self.title +=1

    def changeSong(self, song):
        self.song = song

    def showClubInfo(self):
        print("Name:", self.name, "|", "Song:", self.song, "\nTotal No of Title: ", self.title)
    
manu = EPL_Team('Manchester United','Glory Glory Man United')
chelsea = EPL_Team('Chelsea')
print('=====')
print(manu.showClubInfo())
manu.increaseTitle()
print(manu.showClubInfo())
print('=====')
print(chelsea.showClubInfo())
chelsea.changeSong('Keep the blue flag flying high')
print(chelsea.showClubInfo())
print('=====')
```

my output:

```
=====
Name: Manchester United | Song: Glory Glory Man United 
Total No of Title:  0
None
Name: Manchester United | Song: Glory Glory Man United 
Total No of Title:  1
None
=====
Name: Chelsea | Song: No Slogan 
Total No of Title:  0
None
Name: Chelsea | Song: Keep the blue flag flying high 
Total No of Title:  0
None
=====
```

The output should be:

```
=====
Name: Manchester United | Song: Glory Glory Man United
Total No of title: 0
Name: Manchester United | Song: Glory Glory Man United
Total No of title: 1
=====
Name: Chelsea | Song: No Slogan
Total No of title: 0
Name: Chelsea | Song: Keep the blue flag flying high
Total No of title: 0
=====
```

Comment: Those `none`s are the problem ?

Comment: You're effectively doing `print(None)` because the function is not returning anything but printing itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the `showClubInfo()` function you print the club information so you don't need to type `print(manu.showClubInfo())` because that prints the return value of the function and you don't return anything so it prints `None`. If you want to use `print(manu.showClubInfo())` you should change the code of the `showClubInfo()` function to:

```
def showClubInfo(self):
    return "<insert information here>"
```